# Changing position of options via the admin panel

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, ancestry

I have a below method which is rearranging the position of the radio and checkbox images for my app.

```
def change_position
if !self.position.blank?
existing_model=Part.where("ancestry = #{self.ancestry} and position = #{self.position}") 

if !existing_model[0].blank?
   if !self.changes['position'].blank?  
     existing_model[0].update_columns(position: self.changes['position'][0])
    end
end
end  
end
```

But when I am trying to change the position of the Parent option, I am getting below error in my rails admin panel.

> SQLite3::SQLException: near "and": syntax error: SELECT "parts".* FROM "parts" WHERE (ancestry = and position = 2) ORDER BY created_at ASC

Why I am not able to save the position for the parent options position here?

Any help here?

Comment: the problem seems to be in `where` clause. perhaps `self.ancestory` is `nil`

Comment: fixed. It was because of that only.. Thanks